# how to auto collate all file(*.csv) into one

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerbi

Need help to automate below step.

300 users add file with extension (*.csv) in a shared folder.

End of the day I download the entire folder and extract file (as folder gets downloaded in .zip format)

After extracting, I run command I'm CMD : "COPY *.CSV COLLATED.CSV"

This helps me to merge all 300 file in one go.

I'm looking forward If we can use flow or Power BI to automate this and New collated file  on same folder of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no flow action to read the CSV file from SharePoint library.  If you would like this feature to be added in Microsoft Flow, please submit an idea to Flow Ideas Forum:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/idb-p/FlowIdeas

There is a third-party connector available. Please have a look at this.

https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/read-a-CSV-file-and-bulk-generate-documents.html

For more information,
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/merge-Multiple-CSV-files-into-single-file-using-msflow/td-p/429171

Comment: If my answer helped you, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too